# JPA Eclipse link query.firstResult() & query.setMaxResults() with Postgres

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, postgresql-9.2

Postgres supports offset and limit on SQL statements to support pagination style queries. With limit and/or offset in the queries the results come back much faster from the DB.

I am using Eclipse Link as the JPA provider and by using  query.firstResult() & query.setMaxResults(), the generated SQL does not use limit & offset to narrow the result set. I see that when I turn logging on. I believe it is setting the first pointer in the result set to start at query.firstResult(). This is not even close to being as efficient as using the limit or offset in the SQL directly.

Is there a way to get JPA to use limit/offset or I am stuck with query.firstResult() & query.setMaxResults()?

Answer (score 2):

You are either using an older version that does not have pagination implemented in the PostgreSQLPlatform, or have not configured EclipseLink to use the PostgreSQLPlatform.

Support was added through https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=211691 to EclipseLink 1.1, so check that autodetection is using the correct database platform.  You may need to add the "eclipselink.target-database" persistence property with a value of PostgreSQL if it cannot be detected correctly.

Comment: I put in the eclipselink.target-database = PostgreSQL.             This is my DB version info in the logs.                       Database: PostgreSQL  Version: 9.1.9
Driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver  Version: PostgreSQL 9.0 JDBC4 (build 801)                                                             I Still do not see the limit and offset values being set in the logs for the query. My logging level is set to FINE in the persistence.properties file

Comment: When logging is set to config or higher, what do you see logged for the platform?  It should start with "platform=>".  What EclipseLink version are you using?  Check the platform has shouldUseRownumFiltering() set to true using em.unwrap(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.class).getDatabaseSession().getPlatform().shouldUseRownumFiltering()

Comment: platform=>PostgreSQLPlatform, eclipse link version 2.0.2.                                                      With the jpa jar (2.0.2) I am using, it does not support the method getDatabaseSession() so I had to use getActiveSession(). After running that I get the following exception Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Provider-does-not-support-the-call (There is no English translation for this message.)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.unwrap(EntityManagerImpl.java:2270)

Comment: Unwrap is only in JPA 2.0, so try calling getDelegate() instead.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I did, EntityManager em = (EntityManager)entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().getDelegate(); and then 
em.unwrap(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.class).getActiveSession().getPlatform().shouldUseRownumFiltering();Thats when I get the exception thrown.